Existence of $f$ and independent $Z$ so that $(X,Y) \sim (X, f(X,Z))$
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. Does there always exist a (measurable) function $f$ and a random variable $Z$ such that 1) $(X,Y)$ and $(X, f(X,Z))$ have the same distribution and 2) $X$ and $Z$ are independent?
You may assume that a regular conditional distribution exists for $Y$ given $X$. (This would be implied by the underlying spaces being Radon via the disintegration theorem.)
To be clear, I am not assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are real-valued random variables.
Progress update 1: What I've tried so far: Let $(\Omega_X \times \Omega_Y, \mathcal F_X \times \mathcal F_Y, P)$ be the probability measure such that $(X,Y) \sim P$. Let $P_X, P_Y$ be the marginal distributions: $P_X(A) = P(A \times \Omega_Y)$ and $P_Y(A) = P(\Omega_X \times A)$. Because an RCD exists for $Y$ given $X = x$, there exist conditional distributions $P_{Y \mid x}$ for $Y\mid X = x$, such that $Y \sim P_{Y|X}$. I.e. there exist probability measures $P_x$ on $(\Omega_Y, \mathcal F_Y)$ such that $P(Y \in A) = \int_{\Omega_1} P_{Y|X=x}(A) dP_X(x)$.
Now, if there existed an underlying probability space $(\Omega_Z, \mathcal F_Z, P_Z)$ and measurable functions $f_x : \Omega_Z \to \Omega_Y$ which induce $P_{Y|x}$ then we would be done (excluding problems of measurability of $f_x(z)$ as a function of $(x,z)$). When $Y$ is real, we could use $Z$ uniform on $[0,1]$ and $f_x(z) = F^{-1}_{Y \mid X = x}(z)$ (where $F_{Y\mid X = x}$ is the conditional CDF), as pointed out by Henry.
Progress update 2: As pointed out in this answer, any uncountable Polish space is isomorphic as a measure space to $\mathbb R$ with the Borel algebra. Hence if we assume that $\Omega_Y$ is an uncountable Polish space and $\mathcal F_Y$ is Borel, then we could use the inverse-CDF trick (as pointed out by Henry) on $\mathbb R$ and then isomorphically map this to $\Omega_Y$. (The case for $\Omega_Y$ a countable Polish space is similar by Kuratowski's theorem.) However, I still wonder if the result still follows without needing to assume $\Omega_Y$ is Polish.

Why the close vote? For context, I am trying to prove that if there exists a Markov kernel $\kappa$ then one can write $\kappa \circ P$ as $f_{\star}(P \times Q)$, for some measurable $f$ and some probability $Q$, where $f_{\star}$ is the pushforward probability induced by $f$.

If you have a conditional cumulative distribution function $F_{Y\mid X=x}(y)$ then perhaps you can take $Z \sim U[0,1]$ independent of $X$ and use the inverse of the CDF (i.e. the conditional quantile function) to get $f(x,z) = F^{-1}_{Y\mid X=x}(z)$. Then translate this into your measure-theoretic language.

The Doob–Dynkin lemma guarantees the existence of a measurable $g$ such that $E[Y|X]=g(X).$ This is not enough for your purpose because $E[Y|X]$ loses information such as the spread of $Y$ around the mean and we don't even know that $Y$ is integrable (we really don't, do we?); but, perhaps a look into the proof of Doob–Dynkin could help.

If you don't allow yourself to extend your probability space, the answer can be no.
Suppose $\Omega$ has just 3 points, say $\Omega=\{a,b,c\}$, with sigma-algebra the power-set of $\Omega$, and with probability measure that puts mass $1/3$ each on $a$, $b$, and $c$.
Note there are no two independent non-trivial events. (The intersection of any pair of non-trivial events has probability $0$, $1/3$, or $2/3$. But the product of the probabilities of any such pair is $1/9$, $2/9$ or $4/9$.)
Let $X$ be the indicator of $\{a,b\}$ and $Y$ the indicator of $\{a\}$. The pair $(X,Y)$ takes 3 different values (namely $(1,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,0)$) each with probability $1/3$.
By the above, if a random variable $Z$ is independent of $X$ then $Z$ must be constant. Then, since $X$ only takes two different values, also $(X, f(X,Z))$ only takes two different values.
So $(X,Y)$ and $(X, f(X,Z))$ do not have the same distribution.

Thanks! But I'm happy to assume $Z$ can be on a different probability space.
